# How Annotations works?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This Feild is Required")]
public string EMP_ID { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This Feild is Required")]
public string ADDR_FIX { get; set; }
public string ADDR_TEMP { get; set; }
public string SUR_NAME { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This Feild is Required")]
public string EMP_CONTACT_NO { get; set; }
public string DESIG { get; set; }
public string DEPT { get; set; }
public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
public string PHONE_VARIFICATION { get; set; }
```

When I use [DataAnnotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) on a model. In the view I see some javaScript validation code. I haven't written any code for this, but somehow it's still there.

I would like to know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your property has one of standard validation attributes and you enable client validation, the view engine generates markup and javascript for client validation.

There is some built in dataannotations that works out of the box: `Compare, Range, RegularExpression, Required, StringLength`.

If you want, you can create your own dataannotation attribute that will work on the client. For this, you should add to attribute method:

```
public IEnumerable<modelclientvalidationrule /> GetClientValidationRules
(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
{
    ...
}
```

That will return validation rules. Based on this rules ViewEngine will generate markup and javascript.

You can read about this in details here: [Custom Client Side Validation in ASP.NET MVC3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC3)